# Regex different in Webkit vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this string (from the end of a css background-image url):

```
.jpg")
```

I want to remove the quote-mark and close-parenthesis:

```
var ext = str.replace(/"\)/, '');
```

In Firefox I get

```
.jpg
```

as expected. In Safari and Chrome I get

```
.jpg)
```

Not sure why they're different, but what I do know is that Firefox adds quotes around the url of the background-image whether I use them or not. ie

```
background-image: url(../img/before_after/slides/Brittany_487_a.jpg)
```

returns with quotes around the url in Firefox, but not in WebKit browsers.

Comment: So maybe use: `/"?\)/` to say the quotes are optional

Comment: Are you sure? I'm not getting this behavior on Chrome. What does `str` look like?

Comment: @VivinPaliath str is grabbing the end of the url which is has quotes in firefox and not in chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not really the RegExp that's different, but rather (as you pointed out yourself) Firefox adds quotes around the url, while Safari and Chrome does not.

Hence in Firefox you get:

```
.jpg")
```

which is matched by your RegExp, but in Safari and Chrome, you get:

```
.jpg)
```

which does not matched by your RegExp.

Try changing your RegExp to cover both scenarios, like this:

```
var ext = str.replace(/"?\)/, '');
```

---

**EXTRA:**
Also worth nothing, that in case the file-name happens to contain ") or ) you will not get the expected result. If you know, that the string you're trying to remove is going to be at the end, then you can fix it by using $ which will match only the end of your subject string:

```
var ext = str.replace(/"?\)$/, '');
```

Even further, if you want to cover cases where a single quote `'` is used instead of the double qoute `"` you could do that by listing all the valid characters in brackets: `[]`, so in this case it would be: `["']`, so the whole RegExp:

```
var ext = str.replace(/['"]?\)$/, '');
```

Comment: Yeah it's definitely a browser difference. The question mark in the regex fixes it

Comment: @Adam remember to accept the [*most helpful* answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), not necessarily the first.

Comment: Also worth nothing, that in case the file-name happens to contain `")` or `)` you will not get the expected result.
If you know, that the string you're trying to remove is going to be at the end, then you can fix it by using `$` which will match only the end of your subject string: `var ext = str.replace(/"?\)$/, '');`

Comment: @harbichidian That's true, but I don't see how repeating what the OP said makes this "more helpful"

Answer (score 4):

In the case that the `"` isn't automatically inserted, you can make it optional in the match. Try the regex:

```
.replace(/("|')?\)$/, "");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/R4hfF/

The `?` says "0 or 1 occurrences of the previous character/group".

The `"|'` is in case the quote is single or double.

The `$` says this will occur at the end of the string. If you have the whole line, a ";" might be there (like a normal CSS rule), so you could put `;` right before the `$`.

Comment: So the ? refers to the preceding character, but the \ refers to the following character. Regex is a pain in the a\s\s.

Comment: @Adam Well, the `\` is not regex-specific - that's for escaping the next character. The `?` is a quantifier, and by its definition, it makes sense that it's *after* the target. And by the way, you could've used: `as{2}` :)

Comment: @Adam Well, the "\" is not regex-specific - that's for escaping the next character. The `?` is a quantifier, and by its definition, it makes sense that it's after the target.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a character optional by adding `?` after it. So if the quote is only there in some browsers you can change your pattern to `/"?\)/`.